# AttributeError: type object 'ElementTree' has no attribute 'tostring'

Tags: xml, python-2.7, tostring, elementtree

I have this problem , `AttributeError: type object 'ElementTree' has no attribute 'tostring'`, I don't know what's is wrong, I import to string, It does not work.
Try to follow another tutorial but, nothing.

Is there any other way to convert an ElementTree object into an XML string?

```
import os
import re
import glob
from xml.dom import minidom
from time import strftime
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring
date=strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
os.chdir('/home/guillermo/TclsPy/XML_Level2/')

def prettify(elem):
    """Return a pretty-printed XML string for the Element.
    """
    rough_string = ElementTree.tostring(elem, 'utf-8',method="xml" ,     short_empty_elements=True)
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
    return reparsed.toprettyxml(indent=" ")





for nameXml in glob.glob("*.xml"):
    new_nameXml = re.sub(r'tlmy',r'AUX',nameXml,flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    new_nameXml = re.sub('.xml','_AlarmEnabled.xml',new_nameXml, flags=re.IGNORECASE)#new_nameXml.lower().replace('.xml','_AlarmEnabled.xml')
    match = re.search(r'TSL_TM_TLMY_(.+).xml', nameXml,flags= re.IGNORECASE )
    if match:
        #Si matchea el patron, guardamos en subsistema lo que esta entre ()
        subsistema = match.group(1)
        print "Nombre:", new_nameXml
        print "Subsistema:", subsistema
    else:
        print "No matchea:", nameXml
       # raw_input()
    #<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    TSLFunction=Element('TSLFunction')
    child = SubElement(TSLFunction, 'unit')
    child.text = '<![CDATA[AUX]]>'

    child1= SubElement(TSLFunction,'mnemonic')
    child1.text='<![CDATA'+'['+'AUX::'+'AUX.'+subsistema.replace('.xml','')+'_AlarmEnabled]]'

    child2=SubElement(TSLFunction, 'body')
    child2.text='<![CDATA[out = true;]]>'

    child3=SubElement(TSLFunction,'description')
    child3.text='<![CDATA[--]]>'

    child4=SubElement(TSLFunction,'name')
    child4.text='<![CDATA['+subsistema+'_AlarmEnabled'+']]'

    child5=SubElement(TSLFunction,'minorVersion')
    child5.text='0'

    child6=SubElement(TSLFunction,'majorVersion')
    child6.text='1'

    child7=SubElement(TSLFunction,'lastUpdate')
    child7.text=date

    child8=SubElement(TSLFunction,'creationDate')
    child8.text=date

    child9=SubElement(TSLFunction,'checked')
    child9.text='false'

    returnchild=SubElement(TSLFunction,'return')


    name=SubElement(returnchild,'name')
    name.text='<![CDATA[out]]>'

    returnType=SubElement(returnchild,'returnType')
    returnType.text='boolean'
    label=SubElement(returnchild,'label')
    label.text='<![CDATA[--]]>'

    parameters=SubElement(TSLFunction,'parameters')

    subtype=SubElement(TSLFunction,'subtype')
    subtype.text='<![CDATA[TM]]>'

    prefix=SubElement(TSLFunction,'prefix')
    prefix.text='<![CDATA[AUX]]>'

    variable=SubElement(TSLFunction,'variable')
    variable.text='<![CDATA['+subsistema +'_AlarmEnabled]]'
    print (subsistema)

    tree = ElementTree(prettify(TSLFunction))
    tree.write('../Alarm/'+new_nameXml)enter code here
```

Answer (score 16):

The `xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree` class does not have a `tostring` method. It is a function in the `xml.etree.ElementTree` module.

You have imported `tostring` from the module already in your code. Change

```
rough_string = ElementTree.tostring(elem, 'utf-8', method="xml", short_empty_elements=True)
```

to

```
rough_string = tostring(elem, 'utf-8', method="xml")
```

and it should work.

The `short_empty_elements` parameter is only available in Python 3.4. It does not work in Python 2.7.

Comment: almost work y have this error :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/guillermo/TclsPy/Match.py", line 92, in <module>
    tree.write('../Alarm/'+new_nameXml)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 817, in write
    self._root, encoding, default_namespace
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 876, in _namespaces
    iterate = elem.getiterator # cET compatibility
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'getiterator'

Comment: I see now that the print statements are Python 2 style. So why is the question tagged [python-3.x]?

Comment: I have pointed out a couple of problems already, but I don't know how to reproduce this new error that you put in a comment. A complete test case (see http://sscce.org/) would make it easier to help.

Answer (score 2):

You're importing the wrong thing. `tostring` is a function in the `xml.etree.ElementTree` module, not a method of `xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree`.